# how to get table input sum value depend on select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML part of the code below works when I use it without a table but does not work when the inputs of the form are placed inside the row of the table. Basically the total will be down according to the celestial box. Can anyone help please?

```js
<script> 
$(document).on("change", ".track,[name='type[]']", function() {
  const sum = {
    male: 0,
    female: 0
  };
  $(".track").each(function() {
    const type = $(this).prev().val();
    sum[type] += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#male-total").val(sum.male);
  $("#female-total").val(sum.female);
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <table widht="100" border="1" >
           <tr>
              <th><select name='type[]'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></th>
              <th><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> </th>
           </tr>               
           
           <tr>
              <th><select name='type[]'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></th>
              <th><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> </th>
           </tr>
     </table>     
      
          
          
 <hr> 
    <label> Male Total: </label>
    <input type="text" id="male-total"  value="" />
    
        <label> Female Total: </label>
    <input type="text" id="female-total"   value="" />
```

Comment: `$(this).prev()` never exists because the `<select>`s and `<input>`s you’re targeting are already the first elements in their respective parent. You have to use some other kind of [DOM traversal](//api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), e.g. `.closest`, `.find`, etc.

Comment: So use either `$(this).closest("th").prev().find("[name='type[]']").val()` or `$(this).closest("tr").find("[name='type[]']").val()`. Attribute `width` is misspelled, but, along with `border`, deprecated; use CSS instead. Prefer [`input`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) over `change`. Prefer `type="number"`.

Comment: Without jQuery and with `<input type="number">`: `addEventListener("input", () => { const sums = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".track"), (amountField) => [ amountField.closest("tr").querySelector("[name='type[]']").value, amountField ]).reduce((result, [ key, { value, valueAsNumber } ]) => { if(value){ result[key] ??= 0; result[key] += valueAsNumber; } return result; }, {}); document.getElementById("male-total").value = sums.male ?? 0; document.getElementById("female-total").value = sums.female ?? 0; });`.